# Unknown reason for OnePlus One Custom ROM not booting up

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I personally compiled AOSP custom ROM for OnePlus One (bacon) on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. However, the ROM does not boot up and boots into fastboot mode. If I use the kernel of LineageOS 15 for bacon, the boot animation shows up temporarily but then it boots into fastboot mode. I followed all instructions correctly and the build completed successfully.

**Sources**

AOSP manifest source (Potato Open Source Project (POSP)): https://github.com/PotatoProject/manifest

Device Source (bacon): https://github.com/PotatoDevices/device_oneplus_bacon

Kernel Source: https://github.com/PotatoDevices/kernel_oneplus_msm8974

The developer AgentFabulous has also compiled bootable ROMs from the same sources (tested myself on my OnePlus One)
POSP (Official) for OnePlus One (bacon): https://sourceforge.net/projects/posp/files/bacon/

Does anyone have any suggestion or idea for what goes wrong in my kernel or ROM?
Also, can anyone help me in getting serial console working on the OnePlus One, if this will help me in finding errors in he booting process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the kernel was not compiled correctly. I resynced the repo sources (given in question) and rebuilt the ROM. The rebuilt ROM booted up properly on my OnePlus One. However, there can be one more possibility of the headers being outdated or not functional. My build system was updated recently, which could have played a role in correct compilation of kernel (and ROM).